# Rails server running but not bringing me to my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 alongside Windows 7 to make dev in Rails easier.  I got everything up and running and brought over my projects into Ubuntu.  When I start the Rails server in the project folder it runs just fine, but when I go to localhost:3000 I get the "Your riding Ruby on Rails" generic placeholder, not the root home page I have set up, nor can I use any of the addresses I have setup in my routes file.  If anyone has any experience or ideas of what might alleviate this issue I would be very grateful.  I don't want to go back to developing in Windows... Thanks in advance.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  resources :users 

end
```

Comment: I edited the post to show the routes.

Comment: When you visit the help route, what do you get?

Comment: Actually for some reason this morning all the other pages work when I go to them, its just the root path that is not working.

Comment: when you visit the root path, what do the logs say? (the logs are displayed on the terminal)

Comment: Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-14 10:08:33 -0500

Comment: Does it work if you try     root to: 'static_pages#home'

Comment: Negative. Still the generic place holder page. If I add the code "get 'home' => 'static_pages#home'" and I go to that address, localhost:3000/home that gets the page to display at that address, not the / address though...

Comment: What version of `Rails` are you using?

Comment: 3.2.16 is the version

Comment: Oh I see, delete public/index.html and try again.

Comment: Wunderbar!! Thank you so much, now I can keep working! If you wouldn't mind, could you tell me why that was the issue? I don't like just blindly doing something and not knowing the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and upgrade to the latest rails version.

Comment: I am running Rails 4.2.0, is that the most current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the file public/index.html, it has priority over your routes.